# Install SugarCRM on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, sugarcrm, nosql

Is it possible to install SugarCRM Community Edition v6.5 using a NoSQL DB like NoSQL?
It is not among the supported databases listed on the Sugar website but there are some articles around about people who did it.

How stable can it be? Is it hard to implement?

Comment: I would recommend you to ask this question on http://forums.sugarcrm.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sugarcrm is optimized for SQL syntax and current supported database. if it is possible at all still it will be much of a work for you to stablize and optimize it for mongo db.

Comment: Hey Wisdom, thanks for your answer. Have you read some articles about it?